# Usage of registers in x86 assembly language under Linux

Tags: linux, assembly, x86

Below is a *hello world* program in x86 assembly language. I know what every register is doing, but why can't I use different register instead of these specified?

For example, if I use rbx instead of rax the code doesn't work.

```
section .data
    text db "Hello World",10
section .text
    global _start
_start:
    mov rax, 1
    mov rdi, 1
    mov rsi, text
    mov rdx, 14
    syscall

    mov rax, 60
    mov rdi, 0
    syscall
```

Comment: If you use `rbx` instead of `rax` for what? Your question seems unclear to me.

Comment: rbx in place of rax

Comment: What does `syscall` do? Does it leave certain values in `rax` for you to work with?

Comment: PS: please tell us what language this is.

Comment: as far as i understood it calls the linux kernel to execute the above statements

Comment: assembly language x86_64

Comment: If syscall expect to have something in a certain register, you can't just decide to put it elsewhere. It's like telling you there's a letter for you and then putting it into the neighbor's post box.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Thanks for your support but could you please explain this in more detail so that i get better understanding because  both rax and rbx are general purpose registers.

Comment: syscall expects things to be in certain places. General purpose doesn't mean "I can do whatever and everyone else can read my mind." Read more at http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscall.2.html

Comment: Look up calling standards.  Every platform/language/library has a calling standard.  If you don't have one, how can anyone ever call your functions?  You must have the correct values in the correct places that match the calling standard or ABI.

Comment: The `syscall` will give control to the code written by linux kernel programmers. They decided that code will expect the requested_service number in `rax`. If you will put the `1` into `rbx`, the code will still test `rax`, and find something else there (for example if `2`, it will do not `sys_write`, but `sys_open`). As long as you are executing your code, you can replace general purpose registers as you wish, reassigning them freely, but once you call some foreign code, there's always fixed ABI (hopefully documented), how to call it. You can create own wrapper for syscall to map rbx to rax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call into the operating system, the operating system needs to know what you want it do. On Linux, the operating system looks into the general-purpose registers `rax`, `rdi`, `rsi`, `rdx`, `r10`, `r8`, and `r9`. In these registers, the kernel finds a bunch of values:

```
rax: 0x00000001
rdi: 0x00000001
rsi: 0x00400123
rdx: 0x0000000e
r10: 0x00000042
r8:  0xdeadbeef
r9:  0x00000023
```

How does the kernel know which values represent what? They all look the same! The solution is that there is a convention. First, the kernel looks into `rax` to check what function you want. Function 1 is `SYS_write`. For `SYS_write`, it expects `rdi` to contain the file descriptor to write to (`1`, stdout), in `rsi` it expects a pointer to the data to write (`0x00400123`, a pointer to your string `"Hello World"`) and in rdx it expects the number of bytes to write.

The only way for the kernel to tell which data has which meaning is to use the convention that you use certain registers for certain pieces of data.